# ctx is a required argument that is missing

Tags: discord.py

Help Me with this error "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required
argument that is missing." in the code written below

```
import aiohttp
import discord
from discord.ext import commands  
from discord.utils import get

@client.command()
async def cat(self, ctx):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get("https://randomfox.ca/floof/") as r:
            data = await r.json()
            emb = discord.Embed(title = "Hi!")
            emb.set_image(url=data['image'])
            emb.set_footer(text =f"Requested By:{ctx.author.name}")
            await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: What do you do before the error happens? In which line does the error happen? What is the traceback? I'd guess that in `async def cat(self, ctx)` discord only passes the context object to the function, so the context object would be assigned to `self`, but the ctx argument would not be assigned which leads to the error. Try `async def cat(ctx):`. But without anymore information its hard to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the `self` argument only in classes (unless it's a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`), the command is not in a class, so you simply don't take it

```py
async def cat(ctx):
   ...
```